# Private method implementation compile error

Tags: c++, oop

i have class T

```
class T
    {
       public:
       .
       .
       private:
       void foo();
    }

void T::foo()
{
    .. foo body
}
```

when i try to compile i get
error: `void T::foo()` is private

how am i supposed to implement private methods?

Comment: Can you give a complete, minimal example that produces the error?

Comment: Did you #include the header file if you were writing that body in a .cpp file?

Comment: oh i just noticed its an error from main() where i call foo as if it was opublic method, how can i use private method ?

Comment: Always a `;` after a class definition/declaration please !

Comment: a private method is for using in the class itself. If you want to access it from main(), make it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private methods can only be used within the class.

Difference between private, protected and public? https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance#access-rules

If you want to use it outside, then you have to make it public. Here is a simple example about private and public members

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
    void bar()
    {
        cout << "Private! Can only be accessed within the class";
    }

    public:
        void foo()
        {
            std::cout << "hello world!"; 
        }
};

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    T testT;

    //testT.bar();      <--uncomment this and you will get the error: 'void T::bar()' is private
    testT.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

You might also want to learn about friend concept. If a function is declared as a friend of T class, it can access the private foo().

More details here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/